# How can I load json and use it inside apoc.periodic.iterate

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying add some test data to all of my nodes of type `A`. I want to use a json file which contains that dummy data:

```
[
   {
      a: "x",
      b: 1,
      c: 3
   },
   {
      a: "y",
      b: 5,
      c: 4
   },
   ...
]
```

For every node of type `A`, all these objects should become one node of type `B`. They should also have a relationship.
So I tried it like this using `apoc.periodic.iterate` (because I have millions of nodes) and `apoc.load.json`:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    'MATCH (n:A) RETURN n',
    'CALL apoc.load.json("file:///values.json") YIELD value
     WITH value
     FOREACH (m in value |
         CREATE (v:B { a: m.a, b: m.b, c: m.c })
         MERGE (n)-[r:REL]->(v)',
     {batchSize:500})
YIELD batches, total
RETURN batches, total
```

However this did nothing at all.
I also tried to load the json outside of `iterate`, so I dont have to read it for each node, but I could not find a way to use it inside then.

How could I get this to work?

**Edit:**
This is another query I tried:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///values.json") YIELD value
WITH value AS value
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('MATCH (n:A) RETURN n', 'FOREACH(m in $value | CREATE (v:B {a:m.a, b: m.b, c: m.c}) MERGE (n)-[r:REL]->(v))', {batchSize:500}) YIELD batches, total
RETURN batches, total
```

While running I tried checking if something happens using `MATCH (n:A)-[]-(v:B) RETURN n, v LIMIT 100` but it seems that nothing is being updated.

This is what it should look like (red node = type A):
[image]